# Android calling image picker from DialogFragment

Tags: android, layout, browser, dialog, image

I have DialogFragment class, where i have button which opens new activity with Image Browser,

code for button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( getActivity(), BrowsePicture.class );
                    intent.setType( "image/*" );
                    intent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );
                    startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( intent, "Choose image" ), 1 );
```

and here is BrowsePicture.class:

```
public class BrowsePicture extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private String selectedImagePath;
private String filemanagerstring;
public static String IMAGE_NAME;

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Log.d("URI VAL", "selectedImageUri = " + selectedImageUri.toString());
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            if(selectedImagePath!=null){         
                // IF LOCAL IMAGE, NO MATTER IF ITS DIRECTLY FROM GALLERY (EXCEPT PICASSA ALBUM),
                // OR OI/ASTRO FILE MANAGER. EVEN DROPBOX IS SUPPORTED BY THIS BECAUSE DROPBOX DOWNLOAD THE IMAGE 
                // IN THIS FORM - file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/...
                System.out.println("local image"); 
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("picasa image!");
                loadPicasaImageFromGallery(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I click on button in my dialog, i Can see image browser but i doesn't work like it should, i think there's something wrong with :
 startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( intent, "Choose image" ), 1 );

Thank in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this maybe
`getActivity().startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( intent, "Choose image" ), 1 );`